# Does this two variable limit exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Does this limit exist? How do I evaluate it or prove it doesn't exist?

\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{e^{xy^2}-1}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{equation}

I tried some restrictions to see if I could  prove it does not exist, for example:

\begin{align}
&E_1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x=0 \land y\neq0\} \\
&E_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x=y\} \\
&E_3=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x=y^2\}
\end{align}

but the limit of all those restrictions was $0$.

I tried multiplying and dividing by $xy^2$ so the limit became:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{e^{xy^2}-1}{xy^2}\cdot\frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{equation}

And I could just compute the limit:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{equation}

All I know about this function is that its absolute value is less or equal than $1$, so comparison test doesn't help me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last limit do NOT exists:

$$\lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to(0,0)\\x=0}}\frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=0$$
BUT

$$\lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to(0,0)\\x=y}}\frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}= \lim_{y\to0} \frac{y^3}{(2y^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}$$

Comment: Oh gosh, I thought I had tried that restriction (I even wrote that in the post but I was wrong). I might have done some algebraic mistakes last night.